# Routing users request to access static content to nearest server in aws

Tags: caching, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have content in S3 bucket(in ap-southeast-1 region), which is being server to users via Cloudfront to minimize latency and maximize throughput. We face high latency in this setup when users from USA access content and object is not cached in edge location. Being in B2C business, our content is not hot so we have high percentage of cache miss from Cloudfront. Hence We wish to improve latency and throughput in case of cache miss too. We have explored akamai as well but it doesn't perform well too in case of cache miss when origin server is far.

I have thought of replicating s3 content to multiple buckets in different regions then one of the following strategies, but none of them worked.

1. Create a domain via Route53 to route request to nearest s3 bucket using latency based routing, then use this domain as a origin for Cloudfront.

   - Issue in this case is that bucket name should be same as domain specified in Route53 and there can be only one bucket with same name.
2. Create Cloudfront distribution in each region, which is associated with nearest origin S3 server. Enable CNAME in each of these distributions. Create Route53 entry for that domain and use latency based routing to send user to appropriate distribution.

   - Problem with this approach is once I specified CNAME for a distribution, I can not use same CNAME in another distribution.
3. Another approach will be to detect user's IP to decide appropriate region in application server, then server him specialized URL made for that region. This is not seamless approach since application logic needs to be changed.

What are the possible solutions for this problem? I am open to explore other possibilities than AWS, but coding everything on my own will not be efficient.

Thanks!

Comment: I would look at CDNs that let you push your files to the edge locations instead of waiting for a request at each edge location to cache the file. Something like MaxCDN's "Push Zone" might work well for you.

Answer (score 0):

How about picking option 3, but using [Route53's GeoDNS feature](http://www.cyberciti.biz/cloud-computing/aws/route-53-geodns-tutorial/) to detect the user's IP address instead of doing it in the app ?

Comment: I still didn't get how this can be done. Can there be one URL which will be routed to nearest s3 bucket(via cloudfront) in case of cache miss?

Comment: Yeah I don't think that's going to work with CloudFront.